# Retrieve and store data into a local database using smart contract

Tags: solidity, oracles

For my information oraclize can be use to retrieve data from several data source but what if i need to get from a local database such as oracle,sql, etc. Is there any way of doing it?

PS: I am developing a private ethereum BC with smart contract using solidity & truffle

Answer (score 0):

You can write a code that runs locally in your computer/server using python, js, etc. your co will be reading the variables or logs in your contract and responding to t appropriately. In fact, this is what Oraclize is basically doing (leaving on the side the certificates Oraclize produces). In python, you can use web3py to interface with the network and read logs and send transactions to your contract.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had written my own API with PHP (as a trusted source for Oraclize service) and also used MYSQL database together with Apache web server.

Comment: Edit the question, if you want to add more details